# Android tablet to LCD projector via DisplayLink USB Graphics

Tags: android, wireless, lcd, projector

I want my android tablet to have multiple displays, specifically with a wireless projector. I have a Diamond Video Stream adapter that runs perfectly when i run multiple displays on my laptop with the LCD projector wirelessly. I just installed the DisplayLink USB Graphics driver then it works.

Now, what i want is to do the same thing with my android tablet; To just connect the Diamond Video Stream's USB device to the android tablet (via mini usb to usb cable) and display what ever is happening on the android tablet to the LCD projector wirelessly.

Can anyone lend me a hand on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite probably your tablet's USB just support USB OTG, meaning you can connect usb drives or input devices to it, but I doubt you can hook an USB display adapter.

Depending on your intended use, you can attach your projector to a DLNA media renderer and send video or audio streams via a DLNA media streamer app like twonky:

[Twonky Beam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pv.twonkybeam)

Answer (score 0):

Should your phone support USB OTG, then DisplayLink technology will work.
In the product you mentioned though, you also have a wireless part. 
The Samsung wireless USB chip driver is unlikely to be in the phone and, because it's not DisplayLink technology, it is not included in DisplayLink application in the store.